# Kotlin count standard deviation with generics

Tags: generics, math, kotlin

I want to write a method which counts the standard deviation from provided numbers.

Here it is how it looks like:

```
fun calculateSD(numArray: List<Int>): Double {
var sum = 0.0
var standardDeviation = 0.0

for (num in numArray) {
    sum += num
}

val mean = sum / numArray.size

for (num in numArray) {
    standardDeviation += Math.pow(num - mean, 2.0)
}

val divider = numArray.size - 1

return Math.sqrt(standardDeviation / divider)
}
```

However, i want this also work for list of Double, Float etc.

So it need to use generics:

```
fun <T>calculateSD(numArray: List<T>): Double {
var sum = 0.0
var standardDeviation = 0.0

for (num in numArray) {
    sum += num
}

val mean = sum / numArray.size

for (num in numArray) {
    standardDeviation += Math.pow(num - mean, 2.0)
}

val divider = numArray.size - 1

return Math.sqrt(standardDeviation / divider)
}
```

But when i try to do this i get and Android Studio IDE error, which underlines the '+=' operator and the '-' operator.

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no nice way to genericise over different numeric types in the way that you're imagining; `Int`, `Double` etc. only extend [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html) and [`Comparable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/index.html), neither of which defines [`operator plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html).

However, in your particular use case, you could just take advantage of the fact that your accumulator variables are always `Double`:

```
fun <T : Number> calculateSD(numArray: List<T>): Double {
    //   ^^^^^^

    // ... code code code ...

    for (num in numArray) {
        sum += num.toDouble()  // This *is* available via Number interface
    }

    // ... code code code ...
}
```

---

FWIW, you could get rid of the explicit loops thus:

```
val sum = numArray.sumByDouble { it.toDouble() }
```

or thus:

```
val sum = numArray
    .map { it.toDouble() }
    .sum()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, i have an bug in my method. Maybe you can help? I've updated my question

Comment: Thanks for checking, please see my updated question(update 2)

Comment: Aaah, OK. Thanks. Sorry, i am a bit tired

Answer (score 0):

As @Oliver Charlesworth already answered, what you want is not possible. However, you can write your code **much more concise**:

```
private fun IntArray.std(): Double {
    val std = this.fold(0.0) { a, b -> a + (b-this.average()).pow(2) }
    return Math.sqrt(std / 10)
}

private fun FloatArray.std(): Double {
    val std = this.fold(0.0) { a, b -> a + (b-this.average()).pow(2) }
    return Math.sqrt(std / 10)
}

private fun DoubleArray.std(): Double {
    val std = this.fold(0.0) { a, b -> a + (b-this.average()).pow(2) }
    return Math.sqrt(std / 10)
}
```

And you can use it by calling:

```
val numArray1 = intArrayOf(6, 1, 1, 0,  1,  9,  0,  9,  6,  6)
val SD1 = numArray1.std()
val numArray2 = floatArrayOf(0.6f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  0.8f,   1.0f,   0.9f,   0.0f,   0.9f,   0.6f,   0.6f)
val SD2 = numArray2.std()
val numArray3 = doubleArrayOf(0.6, 1.0, 1.0,    0.8,    1.0,    0.9,    0.0,    0.9,    0.6,    0.6)
val SD3 = numArray3.std()

println("Standard Deviation = $SD1")
println("Standard Deviation = $SD2")
println("Standard Deviation = $SD3")
```

Comment: It works fine, but please edit  the hardcoded size of an array  "Math.sqrt(std / 10)" -> "Math.sqrt(std / this.size)"

Answer (score 0):

```
import kotlin.math.pow
import kotlin.math.sqrt

fun Collection<Double>.stdDevDouble(): Double {
    val mean = this.sum() / this.size

    var standardDeviation = 0.0
    this.forEach { standardDeviation += (it - mean).pow(2.0) }

    return sqrt(standardDeviation / this.size)
}

fun Collection<Number>.stdDev(): Double {
    return this.map { it.toDouble() }.stdDevDouble()
}
```